Distribution of internally standardized residuals
The internally studentized residuals are defined as
\begin{align}
  r_i = \dfrac{e_i}{se(e_i)} = \dfrac{e_i}{s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}
\end{align}
A common practice is to mark an $i-$th observation as outlying whenever e.g. $|r_i| > 2$, by means of an analogy with the appropriate quantile of a normal distribution. Also, one of the several diagnostic tools in e.g. R is a QQ plot for $r_i$, i.e. empirical quantiles of $r_i$ against the theoretical quantiles of $N(0,1)$.
Yet, the exact distribution of $r_i$ is not trivial (see e.g.  Allen J. Pope (1976), The statistics of residuals and the detection of outliers) and unfortunately it is neither normal nor t. Hence the questions:

If $e_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2(1-h_{ii}))$ then dividing by the standard error should yield a t-student distribution for $r_i$. Why it is not the case here? Is this because of the dependence of residuals e.g. orthogonality to the column space of $X$?
If $r_i$ is neither t nor normal, then why would we even expect it to follow the theoretical quantiles of a standard normal distribution?


Flagging an observation as "outlying" is nowhere near an exact procedure, so you might consider why the exact distribution of $r_i$ would be relevant for that purpose.
